# Multiple records/elements grouped to create new structure

Tags: xslt, row, reformatting

I searched and came close to finding a solution but that requires Stylesheet 2.0 and I'm stuck on 1.0.

This is the sample XML I have:

```
<root>
<row>A1: Apples</row>
<row>B1: Red</row>
<row>C1: Reference text</row>
<row>badly formatted text which belongs to row above</row>
<row>and here.</row>
<row>D1: ABC</row>
<row>E1: 123</row>
<row>A1: Oranges</row>
<row>B1: Purple</row>
<row>C1: More References</row>
<row>with no identifier</row>
<row>again and here.</row>
<row>D1: DEF</row>
<row>E1: 456</row>
.
.
```

I want it to look like:

```
<root>
<row>
    <A1>Apples</A1>
    <B1>Red</B1>
    <C1>Reference text badly formatted text which belongs to row above and here.</C1>
    <D1>ABC</D1>
    <E1>123</E1>
</row>
<row>
    <A1>Oranges</A1>
    <B1>Purple</B1>
    <C1>More Reference with no identifier again and here.</C1>
    <D1>DEF</D1>
    <E1>456</E1>
</row>
.
.
```

There is a pattern to this which I can convert using other utilities but quite hard with XSL 1.0.

There are headings within the elements that I can use and the reference text field is multi-line when it gets converted to XML, it creates its own row for each line but it's always in the same position between C1 and D1.  The actual name of the elements, ie  is not important.

The row should break up after E1.  I think my example is straightforward but this transformation is not.  I consider myself not even a beginner at XML/XSL.  I am learning from scratch and then I get shifted to other projects and then have to come back to it again.  TIA.

Update:  Another case I ran into with slightly different structure but I want the result to be the same:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <Field>A1: Apples</Field>
  </row>
<row>
    <Field>B1: Red</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>C1: Reference text</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>badly formatted text which belongs to row above</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>and here.</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>D1: ABC</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>E1: 123</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>A1: Oranges</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>B1: Purple</Field>
</row>
<row>
    <Field>C1: More References</Field>
</row>
<row>
   <Field>with no identifier</Field>
</row>
<row>
   <Field>again and here.</Field>
</row>
<row>
   <Field>D1: DEF</Field>
</row>
<row>
   <Field>E1: 456</Field>
</row>
```

I tried applying an identity transform but didn't seem to work:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match ="row/Field">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*There is a pattern to this*" Could you be more explicit in describing this pattern? I see a group created for each 7 rows - but that could be just a coincidence in the example.

Comment: Yes, that is the pattern and not coincidence.  Every record or group is 7 lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks kind of tricky, but I have a solution which seems to work.  It allows for a variable number of rows after the C1 row (it wasn't clear whether this was always 2 rows or not).

The solution makes heavy use of the `following-sibling` axis, which is probably very inefficient, especially for a large input file.

You can test it out [here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/hyfAYQ/7).

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- Loop through every "A1" row -->
    <xsl:for-each select="row[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'A1']">
        <!-- Add a <row> tag -->
            <xsl:element name="row">
                <!-- Add each of the A1-E1 tags by finding the first following-sibling that matches before the colon -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'B1'][1]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'C1'][1]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'D1'][1]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'E1'][1]" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process each row -->
    <xsl:template match="/root/row">
        <!-- Create an element whose name is whatever is before the colon in the text -->
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before(text(), ':')}">
            <!-- Output everything after the colon -->
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(text(), ':'))" />
            <!-- Special treatment for the C1 node -->
            <xsl:if test="substring-before(text(), ':') = 'C1'">
                <!-- Count how many A1 nodes exist after this node -->
                <xsl:variable name="remainingA1nodes" select="count(following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'A1'])" />
                <!-- Loop through all following-siblings that don't have a colon at position 3, and still have the same number of following A1 rows as this one does -->
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[substring(text(), 3, 1) != ':'][count(following-sibling::*[substring-before(text(), ':') = 'A1']) = $remainingA1nodes]">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yeah wow, thanks for taking the time to do this, I'll test this as soon as I can with some other data sets I have similar to my example.

Comment: @user2300736, if the solution works for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the solution.

Comment: Done.  Both solutions work and I can use either depending on the data that I get.  Appreciate the help!  Thanks,

Comment: It's late and working more on this but I ran into another case similar but structure is different.  Can you take a look at my edit to the question and see how to modify your solution to work.  I tried an identity transform but getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> Every record or group is 7 lines.

Then why not do it simply by the numbers:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[position() mod 7 = 1]">
            <row>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::row[position() &lt; 3] | following-sibling::row[4 &lt; position() and position() &lt; 7]"/>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(., ': ')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ': ')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row[starts-with(., 'C1: ')]">
    <C1>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'C1: ')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::row[position() &lt; 3]">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </C1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yup, I can definitely do this as well and this will come in handy in a lot of situations.  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I'm trying to understand position function more:  How do you interpret this line you wrote:  <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::row[position() &lt; 3] | following-sibling::row[4 &lt; position() and position() &lt; 7]"/>

Comment: It means select the current node and its following siblings #1, #2, #5 and #6. Note that position() is context-dependent. In the context of the current node (A1), the first following sibling is B1.

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching my head for awhile and now it makes perfect sense.  I did use your XSL for similar transformations and able to manipulate it with a better understanding. Much appreciated!